# Brotli compression in Azure Front Door not working without caching

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-front-door

I have a backend pool in Azure Front Door which contains a number of VMs with IIS 10. Brotli compression extension is installed on all IIS. When I hit a VM directly, I can verify Brotli compression is working.

Two Routing Rules is enabled, both pointing to the same backend pool in Front Door.

1. Rule **one** is with caching enabled. This one gets Brotli headers and compression from my IIS pool.
2. Rule **two** is without caching enabled. Brotli headers are not shown in response, and the response is not compressed.

Why is compression only working when caching is enabled? I do not wish to cache **Rule 2**, only compress the response.

**Rule 1 - Brotli working**

[image]

**Rule 2 - Brotli not working**

[image]

Comment: In the rule 2 screenshot, the `dynamic compression` setting is missing. Are you sure you have this set to `enabled`?

Comment: @Kashyap dynamic compression can only be set if Caching is enabled

Comment: I think that's the answer. The brotli conversion is handled by dynamic compression.

Comment: @Kashyap thanks for your answer! So this is a limitation in Azure Front Door? As I do not want to cache my response, only compress it, but this option is not available without caching.

Comment: I'm seeing similar behavior. We have GZIP compression when accessing static resources directly against backend hosts, but if we go through AFD, no compression is taking place to the client. This is problematic given the size of our JS resources that are normally compressed.

Comment: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/40186792-expand-azure-front-door-compression-support

Comment: @RMD exactly same problem! I've voted in your UserVoice suggestion :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Update] This is currently a limitation in AFD, confirmed by Microsoft.

Please vote on feature here https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/40186792-expand-azure-front-door-compression-support